# Push notification service without showing actual notification in expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo, react-native-fcm

Is it possible to use Expo push notifications (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications/) without showing actual notification to user?

I want to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to notify user about change in backend and this would be perfect solution that won't require me to eject Expo and use ExpoKit

I couldn't find any info in documentation, but maybe there is some undocumented solution

If it's not possible then do you see another solution that won't require ejecting or it's unavoidable?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Expo"s  backgroundFetch or taskManeger.
It is more beautiful solution, becase user sometimes deny push notification